java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x94\xD0\xB8\xD0\xBC...'
I checked that mysql (mariadb actually) server is using utf8mb4 using the following queries:
MySQL [testdb]> SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| @@character_set_database | @@collation_database |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| utf8mb4                  | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci   |
+--------------------------+----------------------+

MySQL [testdb]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_server' ;
+----------------------+---------+
| Variable_name        | Value   |
+----------------------+---------+
| character_set_server | utf8mb4 |
+----------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.158 sec)

My JDBC Connector/J (8.0.33) url is :
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?autoReconnect=true&amp;character-set-server=utf8mb4;

Yet, I am getting the above mentioned exception while inserting a row in the table.
What else do I need to check and change?

The db server had the right encoding but the default encoding of the table in which I was trying the insert the value was set to latin1. I found it out using SHOW CREATE TABLE testtable;
I used Unidecode library to map the utf8 string into latin to make it work without changing the column type. Not an ideal solution but it will work for now for me.
